# org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.MethodEndpoint.invoke() method throws IllegalArgumentException : argument type mismatch

Tags: spring-ws

I am trying to migrate existing spring web service to jdk 1.8 and Webphere 9 from current version of jdk is 1.6 and websphere 6. My web service works as expected with jdk 1.6 and websphere 6.

org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.MethodEndpoint.invoke() invokes correct method but the method is invoked with parameter org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlComplexContentImpl instead of XXXRequestDocumentImpl which extends XmlComplexContentImpl class.

Error on console:

```
[err] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
[err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
[err]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[err]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
[err]   at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.MethodEndpoint.invoke(MethodEndpoint.java:115)
```

Error in Soap UI

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">Invalid request</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jdk 1.8 and xmlbeans 2.6.0 I was getting above error 
and root cause was xmlConfig tag was missing from xmlbeans-maven-plugin. Because of which xmlbeans-maven-plugin was not generating the the folder schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans under \target\generated-classes\xmlbeans\schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xmlbeans</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <!--<inherited>true</inherited>-->
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                <javaSource>1.8</javaSource>
                <xmlConfigs>
                    <xmlConfig implementation="java.io.File">${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsdconfig/xxxxx.xsdconfig</xmlConfig>
                </xmlConfigs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```